# Gradient and Hessian of $\sum_i \log \left(1 + \exp\left\{ -t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} \right) + \mu \|w \|_2^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Is my Gradient and Hessian of the following correct?
\begin{align}
f &= \sum_i \log \left(1 + \exp\left\{ -t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} \right) + \mu \|w \|_2^2 \ ,
\end{align}
where $t_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $w, x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mu  \in \mathbb{R}$.

I want to find the gradient and Hessian w.r.t. $w$, that is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial w^2}$.

---

*Partial attempt*

**Gradient**

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} 
&= \sum_i \left( \frac{-t_i x_i \exp\left\{ -t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\}}{1 + \exp\left\{ -t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} } \right) + 2\mu w \ \ \\
&= \sum_i \left( \frac{-t_i x_i }{1 + \exp\left\{ +t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} } \right) + 2\mu w \ .
\end{align}

is this Gradient correct?

**Hessian**

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial w^2} 
&= \frac{\partial}{ \partial w} \left[ \sum_i \left( \frac{-t_i x_i }{1 + \exp\left\{ +t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} } \right) + 2\mu w \right] \\
&=  \sum_i \left( \frac{t_i^2 x_i x_i \  \exp\left\{ +t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\}}{\left(1 + \exp\left\{ +t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\}\right)^2 } \right) + 2\mu I \ .
\end{align}

I Think my Hessian is for sure incorrect, isn't it? because I am getting in the numerator of the first part as $x_i x_i$... how would two vectors just multiply :( ...

Comment: The last part should have the outer product $x_i x_i^\top$ instead of $x_i x_i$.

Comment: ok, can you derive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradient looks correct, but the hessian doesn't. Here's how I did the calculations.

In order to write the function in purely matrix form, first note that the $\{x_i\}$ vectors are columns of a single matrix $X$. Next use $(\circ)$ to denote the elementwise/Hadamard product and (:) to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. 
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$

Define the following variables.
$$\eqalign{
a &= t\circ X^Tw &\implies da = t\circ X^Tdw \cr
b &= \exp(-a) &\implies db = -b\circ da \cr
p &= \exp(a) &\implies dp = p\circ da \implies 1=b\circ p \cr
c &= \log(1+b) &\implies dc = \frac{db}{1+b} \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of these variables. Then calculate its differential and and back-substitute variables until we arrive at the gradient with respect to $w$.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \mu\,w:w + 1:c \cr
df &= 2\mu\,w:dw + 1:dc \cr
 &= 2\mu\,w:dw + \frac{1}{1+b}:db \cr
 &= 2\mu\,w:dw - \frac{1}{1+b}:b\circ da \cr
 &= 2\mu\,w:dw - \frac{b}{1+b}:t\circ X^Tdw \cr
 &= 2\mu\,w:dw - X\Big(\frac{t\circ b}{1+b}\Big):dw \cr
 &= \bigg(2\mu\,w - X\Big(\frac{t}{p+1}\Big)\bigg):dw \cr
g = \frac{\partial f}{\partial w} &= 2\mu\,w - X\Big(\frac{t}{1+p}\Big) \cr
}$$
Now find the differential and gradient of $g$.
$$\eqalign{
dg
 &= 2\mu\,dw + X\Big(\frac{t\circ dp}{(1+p)\circ(1+p)}\Big)  \cr
 &= 2\mu\,dw + X\Big(\frac{t\circ p\circ da}{1+2p+p\circ p}\Big)  \cr
 &= 2\mu\,dw + X\Big(\frac{t\circ p\circ t\circ X^Tdw}{1+2p+p\circ p}\Big)  \cr
}$$
Replace the Hadamard products with diagonal matrices, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
 P &= {\rm Diag}(p),\,\,
 T &= {\rm Diag}(t),\,\,
 I &= {\rm Diag}(1) \cr
 Px &= p\circ x \cr
}$$
Therefore
$$\eqalign{
dg &= \Big(2\mu I + X(I+2P+P^2)^{-1}T^2PX^T\Big)\,dw \cr
H = \frac{\partial g}{\partial w} &= 2\mu I + X(I+2P+P^2)^{-1}T^2PX^T \cr
}$$

Comment: great work, greg. I tried to compute myself but I gave up. Now I got curious and tried to compute the optimal weight . But it seems that I can't make any progress in that direction either :( ... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3100947/find-optimal-weight-vector-sum-i-log-left1-exp-left-t-i-leftwt-x-i?noredirect=1&lq=1