# Find optimal weight vector $\sum_i \log \left(1 + \exp\left\{ -t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} \right) + \mu \|w \|_2^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let the function is,
\begin{align}
f(w) &= \sum_i \log \left(1 + \exp\left\{ -t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} \right) + \mu \|w \|_2^2 \ ,
\end{align}
where $t_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $w, x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mu  \in \mathbb{R}$.

The gradient of the above function is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} 
&= \sum_i \left( \frac{-t_i x_i \exp\left\{ -t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\}}{1 + \exp\left\{ -t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} } \right) + 2\mu w \ \ \\
&= \sum_i \left( \frac{-t_i x_i }{1 + \exp\left\{ +t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} } \right) + 2\mu w \ .
\end{align}

Or equivalently in nice matrix form is--see [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098910/gradient-and-hessian-of-sum-i-log-left1-exp-left-t-i-leftwt-x-i-ri):
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} = -X \left(I + P \right)^{-1} t + 2\mu w \ ,
\end{align}
where $X$ consists of $\{x_i\}$ column wise, $t = [t_1, \ldots, t_n]^T$ and $P = {\rm Diag} \left(\exp \left(t \circ  X^T w \right)\right)$. And ${\rm Diag}$ creates a diagonal matrix.

**Question**: How to find optimal $w^*$?

**ADD**: This problem is referred as L2 regularized logistic regression (Thanks to Dohamatob for the information). It doesn't have analytical solution. So, please ignore this question.

---

*Partial attempt*

I just can't make any progress after setting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} = 0 \Rightarrow 2\mu w = X \left(I + {\rm Diag} \left(\exp \left(t \circ  X^T w \right)\right)\right)^{-1} t$. Can someone help me to find optimal $w^*$ analytically?

Thank you

Comment: This problem is called L2-penalized logistic regression. Please always state the context  / setup of your problems! BTW, there is no analytical solution. Due to smoothness and strong convexity, accelerated gradient descent schemes should do a great job though.

Comment: thank you for your reply, dohmatob. Good to know...