# How to prove the logistic loss function is strongly convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, logistic-regression

The logistic loss function is:
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+\exp(-y_ix_i^T\theta))$$
in which $y_i\in\{-1,+1\},x\in \mathbb{R}^d$. How to show that $\mathcal{L}$ is strongly convex.

My thinkings:
Can we get the $\nabla^2 \mathcal{L}(\theta)$ and show $\nabla^2 \mathcal{L}(\theta)-mI$ is PSD for some $m$?

Comment: Yes, you can compute the hessian wrt $\theta$ and it will be straightforward to see it is PSD. Computing it is a little bit of a hassle but does have a nice closed form expression

Comment: The computation of the gradient and Hessian of logistic loss function is given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098910/gradient-and-hessian-of-sum-i-log-left1-exp-left-t-i-leftwt-x-i-ri

Comment: I just come across this problem again three years later. Is there any condition that we can use to make it strongly convex?

Answer (score 6):

It is *not* strongly convex.
Take $n=d=1$.  You are getting a function of the form $f(x)=\log(1+\exp( a x))$. Its second derivative is 
$$
f''(x) = \frac{a^2 \exp( a x) } { (1 + \exp(ax))^2}
$$
Assuming $a > 0$, you have $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f''(x) = 0$. Thus, there is no positive constant which bounds $f''$ from below. A similar argument shows the same if $a < 0$.

Comment: You're absolutely right. And yet: I think it may be possible to prove strong convexity in the multidimensional case with certain conditions on $(y_i,x_i)$. I don't know this for sure. But this is certainly the case that's most interesting in machine learning applications.

Comment: @MichaelGrant intuitively, i do not believe so. Since each term of the log-loss behaves, approximately, like $\max(0, -y_i x_i^T \theta)$, and therefore any $\alpha \|x\|^2$ eventually 'curves up' faster.